# What are the differences between the design of BOLT11 and BOLT12?

Tags: lightning-network, bolt11, bolt12-offers

What are the differences between BOLT11 and BOLT12?

Should I be using BOLT11 as of today (November 2022) even I like some of the features of BOLT12?

Relevant resources are [bolt12.org](https://bolt12.org/), this [tweet thread](https://twitter.com/LN_Capital/status/1589321548133203968?s=20&t=u5ZGEvEo86FxcuvYAEM1NA) from LN_Capital and this [presentation](https://vimeo.com/user94991385) from Elle Mouton at Advancing Bitcoin 2022.